# FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello Help me pls.......
Advansed thanks for reply
.................................
Notification permission granted.
; FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

```
    <script>
        MsgElem = document.getElementById("msg")
        TokenElem = document.getElementById("token")
        NotisElem = document.getElementById("notis")
        ErrElem = document.getElementById("err")
        // Initialize Firebase
        // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
         var config = {
             apiKey: "AIzaSyBle95lld9XUBB5P-sn2vFciSxcIny-RQs",
             authDomain: "swapnear-f82dd.firebaseapp.com",
             databaseURL: "https://swapnear-f82dd.firebaseio.com",
             projectId: "swapnear-f82dd",
             storageBucket: "swapnear-f82dd.appspot.com",
             messagingSenderId: "390359777744"
         };
         firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging
            .requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                MsgElem.innerHTML = "Notification permission granted." 
                console.log("Notification permission granted.");

                // get the token in the form of promise
                return messaging.getToken()
            })
            .then(function(token) {
                TokenElem.innerHTML = "token is : " + token
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                ErrElem.innerHTML =  ErrElem.innerHTML + "; " + err
                console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
            });

        messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
            console.log("Message received. ", payload);
            NotisElem.innerHTML = NotisElem.innerHTML + JSON.stringify(payload) ;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: is `firebase-messaging-sw.js` added in root folder ? also you can check in chrome while debugging your app on localhost go to `Developer Tools > Application > Service Workers`

Comment: For those who are working in Angular Application `root` mean `src` folder. So Keep file in `src` folder and See whether it is ServiceWorker

Comment: if you get any solution, please post here. I am also facing same error. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a react project that uses firebase messaging, and this worked for me:
I created an empty firebase-messaging-sw.js in the "public" folder, according to the docs.

Folder Structure:

- frontend

  - public

    - index.html
    - manifest.json
    - **firebase-messaging-sw.js**
  - src

    - components