# Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://xxx/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://xxx/firebase-messaging-sw.js')

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send Firebase web notifications from FCM to a client web. I tried doing that and ended up with the error below. I've gone through several links in StackOverflow but it's no use. Both my index.html and firebase-messaging-sw.js are in my root folder

`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration`

Here is my code for the index.html file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Firebase messaging testing</h2>
    
    <p id="token"></p>


    <script type="module">

        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-messaging.js";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = getMessaging();

Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
    console.log(permission);
    getToken({ vapidKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8ymovUhPAmyL6yZmh0t20hf9U5jk_53X7lsDzSXcDA' });
})
.then(function(token) {
    console.log("Token : "+token);
    document.getElementById("token").innerHTML=token;
})
.catch(function (reason) {
    console.log(reason);
});

onMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    const notificationOption={
        body:payload.notification.body,
        icon:payload.notification.icon
    };

    if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
        console.log('a');
        var notification=new Notification(payload.notification.title,notificationOption);

        notification.onclick=function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            window.open(payload.notification.click_action,'_blank');
            notification.close();
        }
    }

});
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-messaging.js");
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase/init.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    const notification=JSON.parse(payload);
    const notificationOption={
        body:notification.body,
        icon:notification.icon
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title,notificationOption);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://.xxx.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276173/failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-for-scope-https-xxx-net-firebase-cloud-m)

Comment: @E3saR thank you but I checked that answer earlier and it didn't help, however I manage to fix my issue today